# Monitoring UI for Apache kafka - kafka manager vs kafka monitor

Tags: apache-kafka, jms, monitoring

I am new to kafka. We want to monitor and manage kafka topics. We tried different open source monitoring tools like

1. [kafka-monitor](https://github.com/linkedin/kafka-monitor)
2. [kafka-manager](https://github.com/yahoo/kafka-manager)

Both tools are good. But we are unable to make a decision which should be included in our deployment stack. Which one is better and why, and in which scenario?

'kafka manager' from yahoo looks the older one and 'kafka monitor' from LinkedIn is newer one

Kafka Monitor- [image]

Comment: For Kafka-manager setup, follow this - https://codeforgeek.com/setting-up-kafka-management-for-kafka-cluster/

Answer (score 90, accepted):

**Lenses** 
[Lenses](https://lenses.io/) (ex Landoop) enhances Kafka with User Interface, streaming SQL engine and cluster monitoring. It enables faster monitoring of Kafka data pipelines.

They provide a free all-in-one docker ([Lenses Box](https://lenses.io/lenses-box/)) which can serve a single broker for up to 25M messages. Note that this is recommended for development environments.

**Cloudera SMM**
Streams Messaging Manager is the solution for monitoring and managing clusters running Cloudera or Hortonworks kafka. It also comes with replication capability.

**Confluent**
Another option is [Confluent Enterprise](https://www.confluent.io/product/confluent-enterprise/) which is a Kafka distribution for production environments. It also includes [Control Centre](https://www.confluent.io/product/control-center/), which is a management system for Apache Kafka that enables cluster monitoring and management from a User Interface.

**Yahoo CMAK (Cluster Manager for Apache Kafka, previously known as Kafka Manager)**
[Kafka Manager or CMAK](https://github.com/yahoo/CMAK) is a tool for monitoring Kafka offering less functionality compared to the aforementioned tools.

**KafDrop**
[KafDrop](https://github.com/HomeAdvisor/Kafdrop) is a UI for monitoring Apache Kafka clusters. The tool displays information such as brokers, topics, partitions, and even lets you view messages. It is a lightweight application that runs on Spring Boot and requires very little configuration.

**LinkedIn Burrow**
[Burrow](https://github.com/linkedin/Burrow) is a monitoring companion for Apache Kafka that provides consumer lag checking as a service without the need for specifying thresholds. It monitors committed offsets for all consumers and calculates the status of those consumers on demand. An HTTP endpoint is provided to request status on demand, as well as provide other Kafka cluster information. There are also configurable notifiers that can send status out via email or HTTP calls to another service.

**Kafka Tool** 
 
[Kafka Tool](http://www.kafkatool.com/) is a GUI application for managing and using Apache Kafka clusters. It provides an intuitive UI that allows one to quickly view objects within a Kafka cluster as well as the messages stored in the topics of the cluster. It contains features geared towards both developers and administrators.

---

If you cannot afford licenses, then go for Yahoo Kafka Manager, LinkedIn Burrow or KafDrop. Confluent's and Landoop's products are the best out there, but unfortunately, they require licensing.

For more details, you can refer to my blog post [**Overview of UI Monitoring tools for Apache Kafka Clusters**](https://medium.com/@giorgosmyrianthous/overview-of-ui-monitoring-tools-for-apache-kafka-clusters-9ca516c165bd).

Comment: There is another tool called [KafkaEsque](https://kafka.esque.at/) which is similiar to Kafka Tool but available under the GPL (see  https://github.com/patschuh/KafkaEsque).

Comment: [KaDeck](https://www.kadeck.com) is completely free for developers. At the time of writing it's probably the best solution for enterprises and developers. It does not require any additional infrastructure setup and delivers detailed insights of the data records including filtering for time windows which is very helpful. It runs as Desktop application and web service.

Comment: https://github.com/tchiotludo/kafkahq can be added to this list for kafka topics management and browsing.

Comment: Having used Confluent Enterprise, I cannot recommend their tooling. While it seems to tick the boxes on paper and the screenshots look nice, the overall user experience isn't smooth. We've had lots of issues with dashboards failing to refresh and showing stats that are contradictory and in some cases outright wrong. We benchmarked our Kafka clusters, pumping around 100MB/s of message throughput (and verifying that the messages were being published), but seeing throughput figures of several KB/s on their dashboard.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to pay for licensing and Kafka cluster support, then you can use [Confluent Control Center](https://www.confluent.io/product/control-center/)

Alternatively, the free route would be to use JMX exporters from Datadog and/or Prometheus/Influxdb (with Grafana dashboards) to see overall system health checks (CPU, network, memory, etc)... Much more information than what you get only by monitoring Kafka processes with Kafka tools

Answer (score 3):

At my company, we used the Yahoo product, we investigated the LinkedIn product, and several others mentioned. My company ultimately chose to use Prometheus+Grafana. Everyone loves it and I'd highly recommend it.

There are two big advantages to Prometheus+Grafana. The first is it does full featured Kafka metrics ingestion+visualization+alerting but it's not limited to Kafka. While our initial needs were just to monitor Kafka, we also wanted metrics on HTTP servers+traffic, server utilization (cpu/ram/disk), and custom application level metrics. Prometheus handles all of the above. Secondly, Prometheus + Grafana are very high quality, well designed, and easy to use. A lot of other products in this space are old and complicated to work with. Prometheus + Grafana are both excellent to work with, they are very customizable, polished, and easy to use. Grafana has a very flashy + functional JavaScript interface that lets you make exactly the customized dashboards that you want. Prometheus has a very polished metric collection engine, storage engine, query language, and alerting system. Something like Yahoo Kafka Manager has much more limited functionality in all of these categories.

If you want to try Prometheus, you need to do two things:

1) install+configure the JMX->Prometheus exporter on your Kafka brokers:
https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter

2) Setup a Prometheus server to collect metrics + and setup a Grafana dashboard to display the graphs that you want.

I'd also say that this is just for monitoring+dashboards+alerting. For management functions, you still need other tools.

Comment: Do you know of a repo of pre built Kafka dashboards for Grafana?

Comment: I setup my own, but there are these ready to go: https://grafana.com/dashboards?search=kafka. I think Datadog has some too.

Comment: Thanks :) Wasn't sure if you knew of others. I currently use DataDog at work, but wanted to setup a homelab to play around with Influx & Grafana

Answer (score 0):

The kafka-monitor is (despite the name) a load generation and reporting tool. Yahoo's kafka-manager is an overall monitoring tool.