# kafka + delete topic by certified tool

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

we have Kafka cluster

as all know in order to remove the topics from kafka and zookeeper need to perform the following: ( one way from many ways )

**stop kafka brokers**

2. delete topic

   ```
   ./kafka-topics.sh — zookeeper localhost:2181 — delete — topic <topic_name>
   ```
3. delete topic from zookeeper cli:

   ```
   rmr /brokers/topics/<topic_name> 

   rmr /admin/delete_topics/<topic_name>
   ```

**start kafka brokers**

we prefer to use a certified script / tool , to avoid human mistakes ( because the number of topics )

second reason - because from my experience during topics deletion and when consumer still affect the topic , topics may not deleted

we can do it manual or build a script ,
but when deleting topics some problems occurs as "mark as deletion" , 
and deletion maybe will be after some time and not immediately

Comment: This is expected, especially for topics with large amount of data. It is not a "problem".

Comment: any way I am asking about tool that is responsible to delete the topic

Comment: Most of the tools mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49276785/monitoring-ui-for-apache-kafka-kafka-manager-vs-kafka-monitor/49292872#49292872), offer this functionality .