# kafka + confluent control center + how to get non enterprise version

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

We installed the docker confluent control center as the following

```
 $ docker run -d \
  --name=control-center \
  --net=confluent \
  --ulimit nofile=16384:16384 \
  -p 9021:9021 \
  -v /tmp/control-center/data:/var/lib/confluent-control-center \
  -e CONTROL_CENTER_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181 \
  -e CONTROL_CENTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:9092 \
  -e CONTROL_CENTER_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1 \
  -e CONTROL_CENTER_MONITORING_INTERCEPTOR_TOPIC_PARTITIONS=1 \
  -e CONTROL_CENTER_INTERNAL_TOPICS_PARTITIONS=1 \
  -e CONTROL_CENTER_STREAMS_NUM_STREAM_THREADS=2 \
  -e CONTROL_CENTER_CONNECT_CLUSTER=http://kafka-connect:8082 \
  confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:5.0.0
```

*after installation:*

```
 #  docker-compose ps
               Name                           Command            State                     Ports
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
control-center                       /etc/confluent/docker/run   Up      0.0.0.0:9021->9021/tcp
```

- Reference:
- https://docs.confluent.io/5.0.0/installation/docker/docs/installation/single-node-client.html
- https://docs.confluent.io/3.2.0/cp-docker-images/docs/intro.html

*Confluent Control Center is a web-based tool for managing and monitoring Apache Kafka. This portion of the quick start provides an overview of how to use Confluent Control Center with console producers and consumers to monitor consumption and latency*

But the problem is -  `cp-enterprise-control-center` need license and not free tool

[image]

**My question is** , since Control center is important for managing and monitoring , we want to understand if we can use somewhere control-center that isn’t enterprise and free

*example of the confluent control center view*

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Monitoring UI for Apache kafka - kafka manager vs kafka monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49276785/monitoring-ui-for-apache-kafka-kafka-manager-vs-kafka-monitor)

Comment: Note: asking for tools is off topic for Stackoverflow

Comment: Dear cricket_007 , thank you for this info , I will keep in my mind -:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kafka Confluent Control Centre is not available as free . Trial version is available for one month. There is other product called [lenses](https://lenses.io/) , you can also check that.

Comment: what are the lead tools that can replace the confluent control center?

Comment: Lenses is also a licensed product

Comment: [Yahoo CMAK](https://github.com/yahoo/CMAK) is the one which is available for free. Not as detailed as Confluent Control Center though.